# run SPD workflow on changes to any field EXCEPT one?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom list. Each item in the list  has 39 fields/columns that need to be filled out and a 40th field that gets filled out by a separate workflow.

I have another workflow that I need to trigger if any of the fields change EXCEPT for one.

Why? Because that field has a custom ID# in it and that field gets populated AFTER the form is submitted. Therefore, there will ALWAYS be a change in the list item. Thus, I need a workflow to trigger when any fields change EXCEPT the one w/ the custom ID#.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one has been able to answer this but I figured it out myself. 
I'm including the answer here in case anyone else ever comes across this and finds it helpful:

1. Create a new field that you will hide from the your SP list and from NewForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx, and DispForm.aspx.
2. Using jQuery, populate that hidden field as such: `$(":input[Title='fieldName']").val("1");`
3. The using an SPD workflow, check to see if that field = 1. If so, run the workflow. AND at the end of that workflow set the field to 0 - that's important.